# Find a graph with critical vertices and without critical edges.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> A vertex or an edge is a critical element of a graph G if its deletion would decrease the chromatic number of G. Obviously such decrement can be no more than 1 in a graph.
>   A critical graph is a graph in which every vertex or edge is a critical element. A k-critical graph is a critical graph with chromatic number k; a graph G with chromatic number k is k-vertex-critical if each of its vertices is a critical element

My question is how to find a graph with critical vertices and without critical edges?

Comment: Do you want to know how to find such graphs in general, or just an example of such a graph?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the easiest example of a graph with critical vertices and no critical edges is a star graph $G=(V, E)$ where $V=\{c, v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_{k}\}$ and $E=\{(c, v_1), (c, v_2), (c, v_3),...,(c,v_k)\}$.  Note that the chromatic number is $2$, but if vertex $c$ is deleted then the chromatic number is $1$.  However, if any edge is deleted then the chromatic number is still $2$.

Answer (score 1):

A complete $k$-partite graph such that one of the partite sets has only one vertex, and each other partite set has at least 2 vertices will work. Deleting any edge will not decrease the chromatic number, but deleting the vertex in its own partite set will decrease the chromatic number.

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be

- $V = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$
- $E = \{(1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (3,4), (3,5), (4,5)\}$

Critical vertices: $\{3\}$

Critical edges: $\emptyset$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).